# iOS: How to properly add my own Frameworks to my App?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcodebuild, ios-frameworks

I have a Workspace with my App project and multiple pure Swift Frameworks.
My Framework **A** is dependent on my Framework **B**.

I go to my Framework **A's** Target, then to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", click the "+". In pop-up dialog there is a Folder "Workspace" where my Framework **B** is listed. I pick it and click "Add".

When I right click on it and "Reveal in Project Navigator" and then look at File Inspector, the Location is set to "Relative to Group" and the path is:

> ../MyApp/DerivedData/MyApp/Build/Products/**Release-iphoneos**/B.framework

Other times it is set to

> ../MyApp/DerivedData/MyApp/Build/Products/**debug-iphoneos**/B.framework

Here is where I get confused:
Is this picked automatically? If it is set to the release-folder I start to get in trouble when I want to build for debug purposes (either **No such Module**, or it doesn't find methods, or...). Do I have to change the scheme of **B's** target? Do I first have to rebuild **B** before I can add the right version to **A**.

It's hard to pick the right question, because I'm quite confused about the whole thing. Could somebody shed some light on this?